# Why this Oracle query doesn't work?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got this simple Oracle statement for deleting rows... but I can't get it work

```
delete from NPEA.tnpe00_all
where EXISTS
  (select 1
  from NPEA.tnpe05_doc, NPEA.tnpe00_all
  where NPEA.tnpe05_doc.n_doc =  NPEA.tnpe00_all.t_doc
    and NPEA.tnpe05_doc.n_prt is null
    and NPEA.tnpe05_doc.n_can = 4
  order by n_doc)
```

The error code is

```
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: what is wrong is oracle error message. (Should be "order by is not allowed in exists subquery" as @vicentmalgrat explains.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use ORDER BY in an EXISTS clause:

```
SQL> SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dual ORDER BY 1);

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

SQL> SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dual);

         1
----------
         1
```

An order by clause in a set makes no sense, hence the error (with admittedly an unhelpful message).

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite it to the

```
delete from NPEA.tnpe00_all WHERE NPEA.tnpe00_all.t_doc IN (
    SELECT NPEA.tnpe05_doc.n_doc 
    from NPEA.tnpe05_doc
    WHERE NPEA.tnpe05_doc.n_prt is null and NPEA.tnpe05_doc.n_can = 4
)
```

It does the same work but in much more obvious way

Comment: Isn't "IN" slower then "EXISTS" for large sets?

Comment: @icuric: 1. They are optimized in similar way 2. this query should be much faster as long as originally OP has additional `join` in the subquery and I - don't

Answer (score 0):

```
    delete from NPEA.tnpe00_all
where EXISTS
  (select 1
  from NPEA.tnpe05_doc, NPEA.tnpe00_all
  where NPEA.tnpe05_doc.n_doc =  NPEA.tnpe00_all.t_doc
    and NPEA.tnpe05_doc.n_prt is null
    and NPEA.tnpe05_doc.n_can = 4)
```

This is working please try this

Comment: `order by` for `delete`? huh? ;-)

Comment: ohh sorry order by is type by mistake